# String RSA encryption in Android

Tags: android, string, rsa

The situation:

I want an application that encrypts an string using RSA. I have the public key stored in res/raw, and as the key is 1024 bits, the resulting string has to be 128 bytes long. However, the resulting string after encrypting is 124 long, and as a result, the decryption crashes.

The function I am using to recover the public key is:

```
private PublicKey getPublicKey() throws Exception {
    InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.publickey);
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);
    byte [] keyBytes = new byte [(int) is.available()];
    dis.readFully(keyBytes);
    dis.close();

    X509EncodedKeySpec spec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    return kf.generatePublic(spec);
}
```

And the code of the function that I am using to encrypt:

```
private String rsaEncrypt (String plain) {

    byte [] encryptedBytes;
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey publicKey = getPublicKey();
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(plain.getBytes());
    String encrypted = new String(encryptedBytes);
    return encrypted;
```

}

P.D.: The code works perfectly in a desktop application, it just crashes in Android.

I really would appreciate any help,

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`String encrypted = new String(encryptedBytes);`

is a bug. The output from crypto transforms are binary bytes. You cannot reliably store them as Strings.

Using `is.available()` is probably also a bug, but I'm not sure in this case.

Finally, it is one of my pet peeves when folks use the default charset versions of `new String(...)` and `String.getBytes()`. It is very rarely the right thing to do, especially in that Java claims to be "write once, run everywhere". The default charset is different on different platforms, which will trigger a bug in your code even if you do everything else correct. You should always specify a particular charset. In every case I have ever seen, simply using the UTF-8 Charset (`Charset.forName("UTF-8");`) will always work and represent data efficiently.